# Do websites have the choice to block 3rd party trackers?

Tags: web-development, tracking

I just got the Privacy Badger Chrome extension and have noticed that when I visit some webpages, I have more trackers tracking me than other websites.

For example, when using the New York Times, I have around 25 trackers but when using LonCapa, I don't have any.

Do websites have the option to flat-out block trackers from other domains or websites?

Comment: This would be on topic if you asked it in the form "do I have control over which trackers run on my website"

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that this question belongs here, as it would not seem related to being a webmaster.  For future reference, maybe Superuser.com would be more appropriate.

In answer to your question - Websites control exactly what trackers they have, as these trackers are added due to actions of the web designer or web master.   Websites can, of-course, only block trackers which they have control over - ie they embed code for in their websites.

As a relevant aside which may help - Web Trackers very often "come along for the ride" when a webmaster embeds functionality into the site - Google Analytics requires Google tracking to work - so when the code to enable Google Analytics is embedded, so is its tracking.    The same is true for a lot of the social media plugins.   Likewise if a page shows adverts, trackers related to those advertising companies are added as well.

Comment: Do websites benefit in any way from "hosting" 3rd party trackers?

Comment: @GeorgeAdams only if they choose to.  For example, if they show ads, then the ads may be targeted at the visitor based on other web activity.  But I agree with DavidGo, your question doesn't fit the rules of the site so is likely to be closed.